# Is it possible for Windows to only change focus to another window upon releasing the mouse click?

Tags: windows, autohotkey, window-focus

I would like to know if it is possible for Windows to only change focus upon releasing the mouse click?

For example. I have Chrome full screen, and I download a file. Then I open Windows Explorer and navigate to the place where I want to move the downloaded file to. Then the following steps happen:

1. Chrome is fullscreen
2. Windows explorer has a small window, in front of Chrome
3. I click on the downloaded file and HOLD the mouse button, in order to drag it to the Explorer window
4. Chrome jumps in front, so I have to drag the file to the icon on the taskbar first.

I think it would be more logical to only change focus to another window if you click on it AND release the mouse button.

I already use Autohotkey to Always-On-Top some windows when I need them for a longer time, so I'm open to suggestions that use that program.

Comment: Well, what I describe is what I intend to do, but I don't think the OS has to recognise what I intend to do. If the focus would not change upon LeftMouseButtonDown, but on LeftMouseButtonReleased, this would work as expected. Usually, even in Windows, only releasing the mouse button confirms the action, except when you click on a button.

Comment: > Windows acts on the first click - this is not always the case. For example, when you open the start menu, everything you can click on, only does something when you release the mouse button.

Comment: I don't think that's a Windows functionality. Either way, "buy a mac" is not really a solution for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139285/discussion-between-john-stoneman-and-tetsujin).

Comment: That would certainly work for this specific scenario, but I'm looking for a more general solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Autohotkey you can create a shortcut to send the active window beneath all other windows, while holding the left mouse button, e.g.

```
~LButton & F1:: WinSet, Bottom,, A
```